# .htaccess regex to redirect to home does not cut the rest of the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am tring to redirect below pages

`http://www.example.com/taksit.asp?urundetay`

to

`http://www.example.com/`

but it redirects to

`http://www.test.com/?urundetay`

Below .htaccess is not working, how to fix it ?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)taksit\.asp(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your existing RewriteRule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+taksit\.asp\?[^\s&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you that one works, but my rewrite rule looks so simple, do you know why it does not work ?

Comment: Couple of reasons: 1. RewriteRule only matched URI without query string and 2. You needed to add `?` in the end of target to strip existing query string.

Comment: Can I kindly request you, if you know how, can you tell me how to fix my rewritecond, I have tried to add ? as character but it didn't

Comment: But there is no RewriteCond in your code and as I pointed there were couple of issues with that. Just use the code as I suggested above.